# .val() equals multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following (simple) code that shows/hides elements when a certain value is selected in a `<select>` tag.

Now I need it to add the class if .val() equals to not only '16' but also '14'.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var Privileges = jQuery('.regeling');
var select = this.value;
Privileges.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '16') {
        $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "inline-block");
        $('.hide_on_call_text').css("display", "block");
    }
    
    else $('.hide_on_call,.hide_on_call_text').css("display", "none");
    
});
});
```

Comment: you mean if it equals 16 or 14? ie. `if ($(this).val() === '16' || $(this).val() === '14') {`?

Comment: What class I dont see you are adding it anywhere? Whats the problem? Also please make [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the second condition to the if using `||`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var Privileges = jQuery('.regeling');
    var select = this.value;
    Privileges.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '16' || $(this).val() == '14' ) {
            $('.hide_on_call').css("display", "inline-block");
            $('.hide_on_call_text').css("display", "block");
        }
    
        else $('.hide_on_call,.hide_on_call_text').css("display", "none");
    
    });
});
```